# How do I get rid of the % character at the end of the printed line?

Tags: go

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var scores = []int {90, 70, 50, 80, 60, 85}
    var length = len(scores) // the len function returns the length of scores
    for i := 0; i<length; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", scores[i]) // Output: 90 70 50 80 60 85 %
    }
}
```

// Output: 90 70 50 80 60 85 %
// Note: How do I get rid of the % at the end of the printed line?

Comment: The “%” is probably your command prompt.

Comment: `zsh` in particular adds `%` to the end of output that does not end with a newline, before it prints the prompt.

Answer (score 3):

Your program does not print a `%`, this is your shell starting a line after the program ends.

To separate your output properly, add a `fmt.Println("")` after your loop, ensuring that there is a newline after your output.

Comment: You don't need the empty string arg - just `fmt.Println()` will do.